# Boot halts or display doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, display

Currently trying to debug why my computer won't "boot". It was having issues resuming from suspend before, but I thought it was [this error](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln300850/dell-27-gaming-monitor-s2716dg-will-not-wake?lang=en) with the monitor, but now I think it's really a Ubuntu issue. I have logs!

What I see:

1. GIGABYTE screen
2. Purple screen, where I am able to open grub and enter recovery mode, that's how I got the logs.
3. Boot log
4. Goes to black and Dell monitor says no display detected. I cannot get into TTY mode.

Here's a few of my logs:

- [kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SnXhhg2mGf/)
- [Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JsKXpvrYYS/)
- [boot.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gszdcnPYRx/)

I could really use some assistance with this. I don't think I changed anything major recently, but livepatch might have updated some things.